# C language - Representing a matrix as an array of pointers

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management, matrix

I am trying to represent a matrix as an array of pointers, and then do certain actions on the matrix.

To simplify further, imagine a matrix with `n` rows and `m` columns,

I defined an `int **matrix` that points to the beginning of an array (of pointers) of size `n`. And every block in this array is a pointer that points to an array (of integers) of size `m`. The result is clear. you have `n` pointers, each of them pointing to an array of `m` integers, overall `nxm` values. So it should be possible to represent a matrix this way.

My problem is that I don't know how to access the integer values of the matrix. For example, suppose I wish to insert values to the matrix. How do I access `matrix[i][j]`?

Here is my code, you can see it is incomplete, I would appreciate help completing it.

```
int** create_matrix(int rows,int columns)
{
    int** matrix,i;
    matrix=(int**)malloc(rows*sizeof(int*));
    for(i=0;i<rows;i++)
        *(matrix)+i=(int*)malloc(columns*sizeof(int));
    for(i=0;i<rows;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<columns;j++)
            *(*(matrix)+i)
```

I want to insert random numbers into the matrix and then return it. I allocated the necesary memory, just need to insert the actual values.

Comment: You access it just the way you have written it: `matrix[i][j]`.

Comment: Oh by the way, in C you [should not cast the return of `malloc`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: So pointer Arithmetic is not needed? and if i want to do it anyway? Just so I know how to do it

Comment: `*(*(matrix+i)+j)=random();`

Comment: Then you should remember (or learn) that `*(array_or_pointer + X)` is equivalent to `array_or_pointer[X]`.

Comment: `matrix[i]=(int*)malloc(columns*sizeof(int));`

Comment: Oh, and to really blow your mind, since addition is [commutative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutativity) `*(array_or_pointer + X)` is equal to `*(X + array_or_pointer)` which leads to `array_or_pointer[X]` is the same as `X[array_or_pointer]`. :)

Comment: I don't think your comment is correct mch. I mean, I know what matrix is. matrix points to an array of pointers. We have no idea what matrix+i points to. however, *(matrix)+i is matrix[i]

Comment: `*(matrix)+i=(int*)malloc(columns*sizeof(int));` : `*(matrix)+i` is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int** matrix,i,j;
matrix=malloc(rows*sizeof(int*));
for(i=0;i<rows;i++)
    *(matrix+i)=malloc(columns*sizeof(int)); //or matrix[i]=malloc(columns*sizeof(int));
for(i=0;i<rows;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<columns;j++)
        *(*(matrix+i)+j)=random(); //or matrix[i][j]=random();
}
return matrix;
```

Note the change of the parentheses around `matrix`

Answer (score 1):

The general pattern for any type `T` is

```
T **arr = malloc( rows * sizeof *arr );
if ( arr )
{
  for ( size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++ )
  {
    arr[i] = malloc( columns * sizeof *arr[i] );
    if ( arr[i] )
    {
      for ( size_t j = 0; j < columns; j++ )
      {
        arr[i][j] = some_value;
      }
    }
    else
      // memory allocation failure
  }
}
else
  // memory allocation failure.
```

Array subscripts are defined in terms of pointer arithmetic: `a[i]` is defined as `*(a + i)`.  `a[i][j]` is defined as `*(*(a + i) + j)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code-

```
int** create_matrix(int rows,int columns)
{
   int** matrix,i;
   matrix=(int**)malloc(rows*sizeof(int*));
   for(i=0;i<rows;i++)
      matrix[i]=(int*)malloc(columns*sizeof(int)); // Fix 1
   for(i=0;i<rows;i++)
   {
      for(j=0;j<columns;j++)
         *(*(matrix+i)+j)=rand();
    }
    return matrix;
 }
```

Instead of doing arithmetic you can directly access it by `matrix[i][j]`. `matrix[i][j]` is equal to `*(*(matrix+i)+j)`.